# Angular 4 - Push Array to Data Model in Another File

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a simple app that allows you to add a server and name it and choose the type. Right now I have it working by using an array within the app component, however, while attempting to create a "server.model" file that outlines a server element and also creates the array to push the content onto, I cannot figure out how to push the data into the correct place.
app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from 'angular-font-awesome/angular-font-awesome';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ElementComponent } from './element/element.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ElementComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFontAwesomeModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
  <app-dashboard
    (serverCreated)="onServerAdded($event)"></app-dashboard>
    <div class="card-group">
      <app-element *ngFor="let server of servers"
      [srvElement]="servers"></app-element>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Server, servers } from './server.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  servers: Server[] = servers;
  onServerAdded(serverData: {serverName: string, serverType: string}) {
    servers.push({
      name: serverData.serverName,
      type: serverData.serverType,
      online: true
    });
  }
}
```

server.model.ts:

```
export class Server {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public type: string,
    public online: boolean
  ) {}
}
export const servers: Server[] = [
  {
    name: 'web.server.com',
    type: 'server',
    online: true
  }
];
```

dashboard.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <form #serverForm="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Server Name</label>
      <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newServerName">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="type">Server Type</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" [(ngModel)]="newServerType">
        <option value="server">Web Server</option>
        <option value="database">Database</option>
        <option value="wordpress">Wordpress</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      (click)="onAddServer(); serverForm.reset()">Add Server</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

dashboard.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() serverCreated = new EventEmitter<{serverName: string, serverType: string, serverOnline: boolean}>();
  newServerName = '';
  newServerType = '';
  newServerOnline = true;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onAddServer(){
    this.serverCreated.emit({serverName: this.newServerName, serverType: this.newServerType, serverOnline: this.newServerOnline})
  }
  onPowerServer() {

  }

}
```

element.component.html:

```
<div class="card">
  <span class="text-center mt-2"><fa name="{{element.type}}" size="5x"></fa></span>
  <div class="card-body pt-0">
    <h4 class="card-title m-0">{{ element.name }}</h4>
    <p class="card-text pt-0"><small class="text-muted">{{ element.status}}</small></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

element.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Server, servers } from '../server.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-element',
  templateUrl: './element.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./element.component.css']
})
export class ElementComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('srvElement') element: {type: string, name: string, online: boolean};
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I think I made some progress, I believe I am now pushing the array to the the array defined in the server.model.ts, but now my:

```
<app-element *ngFor="let server of servers"
      [srvElement]="server"></app-element>
```

Is not listing the default server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property binding is not correct. 
 add your servers[] array into your app.Componenet to bind servers to the app view.

```
import { Server, servers } from './server.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  servers: Server[] = servers;
  onServerAdded(serverData: {serverName: string, serverType: string}) {
    servers.push({
      name: serverData.serverName,
      type: serverData.serverType,
      online: true
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: So I've made some changes to my code, but even before I try and add a new server, there should already be one listed, since there is one already found in the server.model.ts file, but it is not showing up when i use:
`<app-element *ngFor="let server of servers"
      [srvElement]="servers"></app-element>`

Comment: is there any error message? 
*ngFor="let server of servers" 
i think you have to define servers inside your app.component to bind it correctly to the view.. 
[srvElement]="server"

Comment: I was able to get it by making some of the changes you suggested, I also added `servers: Server[] = servers;` to my app.component.ts file and now it behaves exactly as I want it too! Thank you for your help - if you edit your original answer to reflect the changes I can mark this the correct answer